# UITableViewCell with a UIView subclass creates multiple layers on cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have an custom UITableViewCell created with (.xib) and have UIView subclass instance inside cell created from code

table delegate method :

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
    let woView = ModuleView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 400, height: 400))
    woView.addBehavior(self.modulesForSubjects[indexPath.row])

    // remove subviews
    for subview in cell.subviews{
        subview.removeFromSuperview();
    }

    // then add your view
    cell.wiView = woView

    return cell
}
```

my full UIView subclass :

```
class ModuleView: UIView {
override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
}

convenience init () {
    self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
}


func addBehavior (ArrayOfmodulesForSubject: [SubjectsModules]) {
    var number :CGFloat = 30
    var number2 :CGFloat = 30

    print(ArrayOfmodulesForSubject.count)
    for  (i, index) in ArrayOfmodulesForSubject.enumerate()  {

    let yourLabel1 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(number, 40 , 35 , 30))
    let yourLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(number2, 60 , 140 , 30))
    yourLabel1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    yourLabel1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    yourLabel1.text = String(index.score)

    yourLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    yourLabel2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    yourLabel2.text = index.date

    self.addSubview(yourLabel1)
    self.addSubview(yourLabel2)
    number += 30
    number2 += 70
    }


}
```

here is what i get after some scrolling:

[image: multiple layers of labels]

**UPDATE**  rnsjtngus solution, unfortunately also didn't helped (maybe im doing something wrong)

```
class CustomOneCell: UITableViewCell {
var arr  = [SubjectsModules]()
@IBOutlet weak var wiView: ModuleView!
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){

    // Initialize your custom cell

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.setupWoView(self.arr)
}
override func awakeFromNib() {

    print("AWAKED FROM NIB")
    for subview in subviews{
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
        if superview != nil {
        superview!.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setupWoView(arrayOfmodulesForSubject: [SubjectsModules]) {
    let woView = ModuleView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 400, height: 400))
    woView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.addSubview(woView)
}
```

}

Comment: Try moving the  `woView ` initialize to the cell subclass instead of adding as the cell's subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple but, bad solution is
just remove subviews from cell before you add your own view

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
    let woView = ModuleView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 400, height: 400))
    woView.addBehavior(self.modulesForSubjects[indexPath.row])

    // remove subviews
    for subview in cell.subviews{
       subview.removeFromSuperview();
    }

    // then add your view
    cell.addSubview(woView)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: if u want to left some subviews, just check subview before call 'removeFromSuperview()' function.

Comment: great method, but bug still here :(
nothing changed in fact

Comment: did u make your own TableViewCell.swift file? do some removeFromSuperview() in the TableViewCell file.

Comment: For example, in awakeFromNib() function, first remove subviews, second and your own view.

Comment: please check in post update if im doing everythig right according to your answer (multiple layers still here for now )

Comment: U have to remove subviews before u add ur own view.

Comment: move 'removeFromSuperview()' process to init() or setupWoView().

Comment: make sure that u have to remove them before u add that.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, check that tableview.reloadData() call

Comment: unfortunatly thats doesnt work, where is the right way to call tableview.reloadData()?

Answer (score 0):

When you call dequeue the method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib if not.

This means you may well get one that has already had a subview added to it and when you dequeue it again your code would then add a second one. You need to start by removing any existing subviews.

Comment: i have tried really a lot of ways of removing existing subviews, but had no success :(